# iPhone/iPad: Directory Change Notification

Tags: iphone, file

I have an application with `UIFileSharingEnabled`. If the device is tethered, a user can use iTunes (or other programs) to drop new files or delete existing files. I would like to detect the changes to my application's file system on the device.

Is there a 'directory change' (or similar) notification? [Notification
Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) does not appear to have a comprehensive list
of notifications.

I believe Galea's answer (below) would probably work, but GCD is only available in iOS 4.0 and later. Unfortunately, I'm targeting iOS 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grand Central Dispatch, in particular [dispatch_source_create](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_source_create) can be a good start. (by the way GCD is built on top of kqueue, at least for what concerns the event part)

Comment: @Galea: thanks for the suggestion. GCD is only available in iOS 4.0 and later, but I'm targeting iOS 3.2.

Comment: I think your only bet to do this event driven is by kqueue if you want to target 3.2. But even if its a c api, is easy enough to use ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a UNIX system! You can use the `kqueue()` feature to monitor directory changes as they happen.

Here's an example of how to use it: http://blog.julipedia.org/2004/10/example-of-kqueue.html. Or if you prefer, there's a nice Objective-C wrapper class call UKKQueue: http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm

I believe he event will be fired when the new files are created, not when the write operation is finished. So you will not be able to read the files immediately - but displaying the file in a list should be fine.

If you need to read the file (maybe to display a preview of a jpeg for example), you could just wait a few seconds after it's been copied using `NSTimer`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I believe your blog would be a great solution if I were doing systems programming. For the iPhone/iPad, I think I should stick with an applications approach and use notifications via Cocoa/Cocoa Touch and Objective C (if available).

Comment: The Cocoa Touch API is to use GCD, which is still a C/C++ API just like many other low level components in Cocoa Touch. Your only choice if targeting iOS 3.2 is to use the `kqueue` API. There's nothing wrong with using it, and the `UKKQueue` Objective-C class looks easy to use (I haven't tried it myself).