# can we find appstate of other application in our application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application I need to find out appstate of other application. This application is for jailbroken devices and targeted to upload in cydia store. Currently I am working on xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.

For example I have an app 1 which will run continuously in background, and another app2.
And I want to track from app1 the appstate of app2, *i.e.* weather it is active, inactive, suspended. Actually, when app2 is in active state I want to send some data to server from app1, where app1 is continuously running in background. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you state that app2 runs continiously in the background, you might be able to just save its state in a file so that app1 can read it as soon as its active. App1 writes data to another file so that app2 can read it.
This should be the easiest way as there is no private API needed, you only need to write to folders outside the sandbox.
To detect directory changes you might want to look at this question: [iPhone/iPad: Directory Change Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067809/iphone-ipad-directory-change-notification)